# Meaning of 'all president'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> All President Biden’s New Spending

It is [the news title](https://www.wsj.com/articles/all-president-bidens-new-spending-33735c0a?st=kybp4rlp35kbbja&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink). I feel the title implies mockery but can not figure out exactly. I see 'all' is an adjective because it comes before a noun but I am not able to find any appropriate meaning in dictionaries.

Please someone explain it with plain English. Thanks.

Comment: It's poorly written, even for a newspaper headline, which are notorious for using weird grammatical constructions.

Comment: Shin, the title **does not** "imply mockery".  It's a completely neutral title.  (Also FYI.  You don't "imply mockery".  The writer is either mocking someone, or not.)

Comment: @Fattie I feel like Shin's statement is reasonable, they understood the phrasing as suggesting that the writer might be mocking Biden, something that it is reasonable to describe as implying mockery. The writer is either mocking someone or not, but the subject of implies is the *title*, not the writer

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I can agree, Tristan.  I can "imply" that Steve cheats on his taxes."  (If I said something like "Steve's taxes are interesting aren't they?")  However, if I am mocking Steve ("Steve always sounds like a doofus, 'heyyyyy guyssss', Steve talks so slowly! Har!") I am simply mocking Steve.  I can't "imply mocking" Steve.  I can imply some characteristic of Steve.  But "mocking" is something I do to Steve.  Hence, for me, "implies mockery" doesn't really work.

Comment: (Yes, I appreciate the title, not the writer, is the subject. For me it would be like saying "the title implies being long" or "the title implies a spelling error".  Rather, "the title is long" or "the title has a spelling error")

Comment: It's a standard possessive. Like: All John's old expenses. versus: All John's new spending.

Comment: You know how Odin is the All-Father? ;)

Comment: @Lambie Or perhaps more appropriately, "All the President's Men".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not "All President", but "All spending".

The word "President Biden's" is a determiner of "spending", and "All" is a predeterminer. Both are linked to "Spending".

This could be paraphrased as "All spending by President Biden".

You can't tell if a word is an adjective just because it comes before a noun.  Determiners ("the", "my", "John's" "Some" etc) also come before nouns. Determiners are not adjectives.  Also nouns can come before nouns "chicken soup, company policy".

There is no apparent mockery in the headline.

Comment: I guess the OP is parsing it similar to phrases like "Former President Trump's ...". Grammatically, it's ambiguous what "All" modifies, you have to examine the entire sentence to figure out what makes sense.

Comment: @Barmar  In what way is it ambiguous?  I can see why its difficult to parse - newspaper headlines often are - but only one realistic interpretation.

Comment: @MikeB That's why I said "grammatically". The grammar doesn't indicate what "All" modifies, you have to determine what is a realistic interpretation.

Comment: Native english speaker and *I* couldn't parse it. The best I could figure was "All-President Biden's Spending." Like "All-father" or "All-spice". So I understand the reading of it as some kind of mocking honorific.

Comment: Another way to look at it: "All [of] President Biden's New Spending".

Comment: @teepeemm You beat me by a second! Another way to look at this is: "All **of** President Biden's Spending".  I'm not 100% on this but dropping the 'of' in this kind of situation is relatively new.  It seems similar to how 'ly' is disappearing.

Comment: James K, congratulations on becoming the [highest-rep user on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) - it may also interest you to know that you're only the 2nd user on the entire SE network (after [Gilles](https://stackexchange.com/users/164368/gilles-so-stop-being-evil?tab=accounts)) to reach six-figure reputation on **three** different sites (on all of which you were the *second* highest-rep user at the time).

Comment: @JimmyJames: Well, keep in mind that this *is* a newspaper headline, and those have long had the tendency to omit [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_word) like "of" or "the", even when they'd be used within the article text.

Comment: @JohnFilleau really? To me as a native (British) English speaker this is such a natural phrasing for a headline that I don't know how else it could reasonably be rephrased (noting as dan04 does, that stopwords like "of" and "the" are typically omitted in such headlines)

Comment: @dan04 After writing that, I realized that the idea it was a new-ish thing to drop 'of' was completely wrong when the verse "all the King's horses" from 'Humpty Dumpty' came to mind.

Comment: @tristan Yes, really. Why would I like about something like that? People have different viewpoints and consume words differently. Who knew?

Answer (score 10):

It's "All [of] President Biden's Spending". All of the spending done by President Biden. Those words aren't mocking, just by themselves, though the article may or may not be. If you did a graph of the sentence you'd see that "all" and "spending" belong together, "President Biden's" specifies which spending we're talking about.

Whose spending? President Biden's!

How much spending? All of it!

Answer (score 8):

"All" modifies "Spending", not "President".  Taking the headline one piece at a time, right to left:

- **Spending** — Money that is planned to be spent by the US federal government.
- **New** Spending — The spending is new, i.e., part of the new 2024 budget proposal just released today, as opposed to existing spending carried over from the 2023 budget.
- **President Biden's** New Spending — The budget proposal was made by President Joe Biden.  In the United States, *Congress* ultimately has the power over fiscal decisions, but the President's budget is considered an important starting point for negotiations.  If a member of Congress, such as Speaker of the House Kevin McCarthy, were to write up a counterproposal, then news websites would start contrasting “McCarthy's budget” with “Biden's budget”.
- **All** President Biden's New Spending — *The Wall Street Journal* purports to be listing *all* of the new spending items, rather than just *some* of them.

Note that newspaper headlines tend to be written in an abbreviated [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese) style of English.  In particular, [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_word) are often omitted.  Perhaps you would find the alternative wording “All **of** President Biden's Spending” less confusing.